# CakePHP Checkbox Selecting the row

Tags: php, cakephp, checkbox, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to make a checkbox select the table row. and pass it to another controler. but it is passing only 1 checked box.

In my **View.ctp**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>select</th>
    </thead>
    <?= $this->Form->create('test', ['id' => 'test' , 'method'=>'POST', 'url'=>'/encomendas/fastadd']) ?>
    <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= h($item->id) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($item->name) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($item->action) ?></td>
            <td>
            <?= $this->Form->checkbox('select', ['value' => '1']);?>
            <?= $this->Form->hidden('id', ['default' => $item->id]);?>

            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?= $this->Form->button('send') ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
</table>
```

And in

```
debug($this->request->data());
```

it returns only 1 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass select array to get all the checkbox values, as :

```
   <?= $this->Form->checkbox('select.', ['value' => '1']);?>
```

OR

```
     <?= $this->Form->checkbox('select[]', ['value' => '1']);?>
```

In this way, you can get all the values.